# how google home app can auto fetch wifi password on android?

Tags: android, wifi

As you and I already know, All apps on the android can't read other app's data  basically without root. (since sandbox system.)

But recently released google Home app read saved wifi password on the phone and connect device with its password .
How can it be? I couldn't understand this behavior is possible.

I confirmed that works even though I logged out google account.
(It means wifi password is coming from local device's saved configuration).

Google announced that auto fetch feature works after lollipop only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm asking myself this question too. From my experience maybe also Amazon Alexa companion app has this feature.

Comment: Actually, Amazon is saving wifi password via amazon account.

Comment: OK I got it. Btw I asked a Google Developer Relation guy and he says this API is not available to the public, but only Google or primary partners can access it.

Comment: @AkarshSatija sorry but I don't know